# Add a numpy array to another numpy array in a for loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have to arrays:

```
input = np.array([])
filled_orders_buy = np.array([])
```

my code looks like this:

```
   for index, row in islice(df_all_orders.iterrows(), 1, df_all_orders.index[-1]): 
                input = np.array([df_all_orders.loc[index, 'price'],df_all_orders.loc[index, 'amount']])
                filled_orders_buy = np.append(filled_orders_buy,input)
```

What I have is the following:

[1.08094e-03 3.70000e+01 1.07151e-03 1.50000e+01 1.08353e-03 1.50000e+01]

What I need is:

```
[[1.08094e-0,3 3.70000e+01],[ 1.07151e-03, 1.50000e+01],[ 1.08353e-03 ,1.50000e+01]]
```

Please do not put it as duplicates as of course I tried alternative as concatenate or vstack... I am just stuck here! Thanks

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: You have to mention how to shape your array... I do not know how many arrays I will have to append to my array as my data are really long.

Comment: I did not understand your previous message... this is part of a much bigger code, I just need to do that..

Comment: I just changed it

Comment: So you're stepping through all the rows *except* the first one?

Comment: yes exactly, need it that way

Comment: You likely shouldn't step through the row separately, but work on the whole dataframe at once. See my answer as an example to get you started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all arrays to be appended have 2 elements, then you can do this:

```
filled_orders_buy = np.empty((0,2), float)
for index, row in df_all_orders:
            input = np.array([df_all_orders.loc[index, 'price'],df_all_orders.loc[index, 'amount']]).reshape(1,-1)
            filled_orders_buy = np.append(filled_orders_buy,input, axis = 0)
```

Axis 0 is used for vertically appending data, but for that you need similar dimension in the empty array. Hence `np.empty`.

EDIT:
In addition, your input array is of (2,) dimension that is 1D, hence you need to reshape it. Please let me know if this works.

Comment: I have the same issue as before: ` all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions`

Comment: Got the issue, the dimension of input array is (2,), reshape it using (1,-1). I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly you need is `np.vstack()` function.
[Documentation Here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html)

It will attach the new array the way you want it.

Comment: As I said I already tried that, the two arrays needs to have the same dimension

Answer (score 0):

This requires a bit of guess work, since the example code is incomplete, but you may just need:

```
filled_order_buy = df_all_orders.loc[1:, ['price', 'amount']].values
```

to get you a 2-dimensional NumPy array of the data you want. This would replace the full for-loop.

Depending on the next steps in your code, perhaps you don't even need the `.values` part, and can just use the result dataframe as input for your next operations.